# How can I ignore CDATA content while using XML::Parser?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm parsing a number of XML's that provided to me by external party and they're definitely not going to change them; these pesky XML's contains HTML inside CDATA sections and XML::Parser chokes on them.

Is there any way to overcome this besides stripping CDATA entirely?

**Edit:**

Original error was "not well-formed (invalid token)".

I'm sorry that I didn't posted test case right away. After some research I became for some reason convinced that inside CDATA should be valid XML so I posted this question.

Thanks to @ikegami for working test case and to @mirod for very probable and not obvious reason of such behaviour - encoding mismatch.

True reason posted below as an answer.

Comment: It might help if you provide some sample data (and the code you've tried so far).

Comment: Also define "chokes on them:" Does it give you an error message? If you XML is badly formed, you might have to clean up the data first or try a different, more flexible XML parser.

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem. Your claims have been demonstrated (at least partially) incorrect.

Comment: You're right, it's not a general problem. I'll try to understand it better. By "chokes" I meant error like "not well-formed (invalid token)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after minimizing my XML I was able to track reason of these errors: it's a Vertical Tab special symbol.

Crazy!

I was able to fix my files with this snippet:

```
perl -CSDA -pe 'tr/\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19//d' bad.xml > good.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

XML::Parser should not choke on proper CDATA sections. Basically anything goes within CDATA except for `]]>`, **as long as it's character data**, which means no random binary, which doesn't seem to be your case, and no data in an encoding that is not compatible with the one that's declared (explicitly or implicitly) for the document. Which may be the problem here.

It would not surprise me if your problem was that there is no encoding  declaration in the document, so it is assumed to be in UTF-8 by the parser, but the HTML data is in latin-1, or windows-1252, which produces characters that are invalid when read as UTF-8.

Depending on your data you may be able to force the encoding to latin1, if the XML data itself is not specifically in UTF-8, usinf the XML::Parser option `ProtocolEncoding => 'ISO-8859-1'`, or you may need to convert the encoding of the text within the CDATA sections, pre-parsing.

Note that using a different parser will probably not be helpful, as by design XML parsers are supposed to stop when encountering non well-formed XML

Answer (score 3):

XML::Parser handles CDATA blocks perfectly well. Maybe you need to update XML::Parser or the underlying `expat` library, or maybe your problem is elsewhere. Hard to tell, since you did not demonstrate your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
use XML::Parser  qw( );

sub f {
   local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
   local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq  = 1;
   return Dumper($_[0]);
}

my $parser = XML::Parser->new(
   Handlers => {
      Start => sub { say "Start of $_[1]"; },
      End   => sub { say "End of $_[1]"; },
      Char  => sub { say "Char: " . f($_[1]); },
   },
);

$parser->parse(<<'__EOI__');
<root>
<![CDATA[
   <html>
   <foo>test > test</foo><br>
   </html>
]]>
</root>
__EOI__
```

```
Start of root
Char: "\n"
Char: "\n"
Char: "   <html>"
Char: "\n"
Char: "   <foo>test > test</foo><br>"
Char: "\n"
Char: "   </html>"
Char: "\n"
Char: "\n"
End of root
```